# I cant access my localhost using my PC ip. For Our mobile APP

Tags: android, server, connection, localhost, ip

Can someone help me we have a mobile app for our capstone project i ask my friend to make it(I don't have knowledge for android developing) but i'm the one who make for our web app.he added a variable to enter hostname  .the problem is my friend test it it connected using ip/CapstoneFiles ->(Foldername codeigniter). but when i try it it won't connect using IP/CapstoneFiles. i already disable my firewall and antivirus.. My pc is connected to Prepaid wifi via wired connection and i connect my phone via wifi

Comment: `.he added a variable to enter hostname .` Ok. But you are typing more than that. Only give ip then.

Comment: But.... Why dont you ask your friend? Het should have tested all.

Comment: And the port. Which port is used?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows you can get IP by command ipconfig and for linux it's ifconfig
Change the IP wherever used in the project with current IP you're getting by command.
Your PC and Phone should be connected to the same network.

Comment: i use ipv4 address:192.168.254.100
in mobile app i enter:192.168.254.100/CapstoneFiles. My Mobile is connected to my wifi

Comment: connect your system to the same wifi on which your mobile is connected then try, Make sure  **192.168.254.100/CapstoneFiles**  providing response on your local machine

Answer (score 0):

See if you are running it at //localhost:8080 port then use URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/" in your android app to access the server as this translates to localhost for the application
As you must know your application has its own pid and ports within so you will be required to use this
let me know if unclear

Comment: //localhost:80/CapstoneFiles
i try http://10.0.2.2/ but it won't connect

Comment: you are required to run your server at localhost:8080/CapstoneFiles and use the URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/" and then you are required to pass CapstoneFiles as a parameter in your Get request to webservice